# Issues with OpenCV common pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install openCV on my Mac, and have gotten to the point of calling this command:

pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

and get the error:

Variable 'prefix not defined in '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc'

I've tried looking online and cannot find anything about this error. Any advice?